# How to transform user input string into correct object type

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I am using Python (2.7) along with Natural Language Toolkit (3.2.1) and WordNet. I am *very* new to programming.

I am trying to write a program which asks the user for a word, then prints synonym sets for that word, then asks the user which synonym set it wants to see the lemmas for.

The problem is that `raw_input` only accepts strings, so when I try to use the method `.lemma_names()` on the user input, I get the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lemma_names'`.

Here is the code:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

w1 = raw_input ("What is the word? ")

#This prints the synsets for w1, thus showing them what format to use in the next question.

for synset in wn.synsets(w1):
    print synset

#This asks the user to choose the synset of w1 that interests them.

synset1 = raw_input ("Which sense are you looking for? [Use same format as above]")

#This prints the lemmas from the synset of interest.

for x in synset1.lemma_names():
    print x
```

My question is, how do I transform the user's input from a string to a synset type which I can use the `.lemma_names()` method on?

I apologize if this question is so basic as to be off-topic. If so, let me know.

Comment: Before you write any more code, download [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/). Use its debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

w1 = raw_input ("What is the word? ")

synset_dict = dict()
for synset in wn.synsets(w1):
    name = synset.name()
    synset_dict[name] = synset
    print name

synset1 = raw_input ("Which sense are you looking for? [Use same format as above] ")

if synset1 in synset_dict:
    synset = synset_dict[synset1]
    for lemma in synset.lemma_names():
        print lemma
```